# How to form json body having array of dynamic length?

Tags: arrays, json, dart, flutter

I have a list of items. The length of this list can vary from 0 to any big number. I have to send data of each item in an array in a post request to my server. I use `jsonEncode` to convert my body to json but how do I add data of dynamic length?

```
{
        "item_id": "abcd",
        "item_qty": 2,
        "item_cost": 6,
        "item_name": "defg"
      }
```

Comment: from the think i could understand . i think you can just iterate throw your list using forEach or  a for loop and send post request  . i hope you can give more details maybe i can help you

Comment: There are more values in the body other than this array and I obviously want to have only one request for all the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about what you're trying to do, but given that you have an array like

`a = [ 1, 2, 3]` you can do:
`obj = {}; for ( i in a ) { obj["val" + i] = a[i]; }`

`obj` will now be `{val0: 1, val1: 2, val2: 3}`

If for example you have a list of form items:

```
var itms = $( ":input" );
obj = {};
for ( i in itms ) { obj[ itms[i].name ] = itms[i].value; }
```

`obj` will now contain all the input elements (inputs, textareas, selects, buttons) and have the keys of their respective `name`s and the corresponding values will be the elements' actual values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your json to look like this:

```
  {
    "item_id": "abcd",
    "item_qty": 2,
    "item_cost": 6,
    "item_name": "defg"
    "item_length": 100
  }
```

then add the item_length key to your item object and then call jsonEncode function on the object.

Comment: But values will be different for each item which I will get from an array of objects.

Comment: ok, do you want the end json to look something like this?
`[{ "item_id": "abcd",
    "item_qty": 2,
    "item_cost": 6,
    "item_name": "defg"
    "item_length": 100**
 },
 { "item_id": "abcd",
    "item_qty": 2,
    "item_cost": 6,
    "item_name": "defg"
    "item_length": 100**
 }]`

Comment: no, that's invalid JS - `because of **` and JSON - because you're missing an comma before `"item_length"`

Comment: I want my json to look like this - `[{
        "item_id": "abcd",
        "item_qty": 2,
        "item_cost": 6,
        "item_name": "defg"
      }, {
        "item_id": "abcd",
        "item_qty": 2,
        "item_cost": 6,
        "item_name": "defg"
      }, {
        "item_id": "abcd",
        "item_qty": 2,
        "item_cost": 6,
        "item_name": "defg"
      }]` - and there can be any number of such structures in the array.

Comment: `var length = (json.decode(response.body) as List).length` will get you the all the number of structures(object in the json array) in the json.